# Is it a good idea to use CakePHP for Facebook App development project

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp

I want to develop, facebook app, iframe app running on Facebook.com.

Is it a good idea to use CakePHP frame work for this? My app will also have Paypal integration.

I am still learning CakePHP.

Thanks,
Hardik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently developed a Facebook app with CakePHP and it works great. If you're developing an iframe app, then the limitations of the backend technologies are the same limitations that you'd experience outside of the Facebook environment. If you're concerned about the benefits/drawbacks of CakePHP as a PHP framework, then I'd check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249984/php-framework-decision-analysis-paralysis.

If you are new to CakePHP, then you'll obviously find some difficulty, since there is a learning curve, but as far as using it within Facebook, you'll find that most of the issues will be surrounding the frontend, and this has nothing to do with CakePHP.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently made a few Facebook Applications in CakePHP and they work just fine. Stick your whole Facebook Session handling in the AppController's beforeFilter() method so every other controller has your Facebook Session and it's pretty easy from there.